# Remove link functionality JointJS

Tags: jointjs

I have a link connected between two elements. When I mouseover on the link, remove option (X) is displayed.

Is it possible to catch remove event externally? I want to remove the link on click of (X) icon but, before hand I want to execute a customized function.

[JointJS link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwJhU.png)

Answer (score 5):

You can listen to the element *remove* event on the graph and see if the removed element is a link and then execute your logic.

```
graph.on('remove', function (cell) {
    if (cell.isLink()) {
        // execute your custom logic
    }
}
```

This remove event will get fired when you click on (X) icon of a link.